# System Error &H80070057 caused by conditional formatting

Tags: conditional-formatting

On opening a file I got the System Error &H80070057. I couldn't find an answer that corrected it on my file but while trying to figure it out I was notified by Excel that there was a backup file that was repaired. The MS found the error in my conditional formatting (though it had worked fine for years, until O365).

On opening the repaired file, I found 3 conditional format configurations gone. The formats are basic, they just change the color of cells based on the numberer content e.g. turn cells red if the contents are <5. I put the formatting back in and everything seems to work again. How can I prevent this from happening in the future?